# Best way to DRY in create/update model forms in django

Tags: python, django

How do you manage your model forms for create or updated operations?. I want to look if there is way to respect the DRY django’s philosophy, like one more dynamic ModelForm class or something like that to handle both operations instead of two classes:

```
class EmployeeCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  ...
class EmoloyeeUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
....
```

I use model form factory and instance parameter:

```
Employeeform = model_form_factory()
form = EmployeeForm(instance=SomeModel.objects.get....)
```

But what if I want to keep any model pk field as read only during updating (i.e. Employeer id), changing widget fields (i.e. model foreign keys by default shows as html select tag but i want them as character field, that’s why I’m using instance parameter). Actually I achieved this with what i mentioned, creating 2 classes for its related operations and defining widgets with attrs.
Thanks.